# why lock_guard can get an already locked mutex by unique_lock? - still questions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am studying [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030862/why-lock-guard-can-get-an-already-locked-mutex-by-unique-lock) and thought that I will get an answer, but I still have a question.

I post the the code here for convenience:

```
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::string data;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;

void worker_thread()
{
    // Wait until main() sends data
    std::cout << "------------------------\n";
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});

    // after the wait, we own the lock.
    std::cout << "Worker thread is processing data\n";
    data += " after processing";

    // Send data back to main()
    processed = true;
    std::cout << "Worker thread signals data processing completed\n";

    // Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up
    // the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);

    data = "Example data";
    // send data to the worker thread
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        ready = true;
        std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
    }
    cv.notify_one();

    // wait for the worker
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
    }
    std::cout << "Back in main(), data = " << data << '\n';

    worker.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Should not the statement `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);` block the main thread because mutex `m` is locked by `worker_thread`? If yes, isn't the statement `cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});` after it unnecessary in this example? When main thread can lock the mutex, `processed` will be already true.

Comment: `condition_variable::wait` unlocks the mutex

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I know. The question is, that how can it lock the mutex in the preceding line? Or it should not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why lock\_guard can get an already locked mutex by unique\_lock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030862/why-lock-guard-can-get-an-already-locked-mutex-by-unique-lock)

Comment: Why should it not be able to? In both threads, the mutex is only locked for a short period: in `main`, until the closing brace is reached; in the worker, until `cv.wait` call. One of these happens first, the other happens second. I'm not sure I at all understand the source of your confusion. It seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @AlanStokes The post you are referring to does not answer my question.

Comment: @franz1 Yes it does. "The important thing you missed is that wait unlocks the mutex passed in."

Comment: @AlanStokes you are just repeating the answers from the other post, which did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `wait` unlocks the mutex for the duration of the wait. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait.

EDIT: Which is explicitly stated in the answer to the question you linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32030975/212870

EDIT 2: It is not true that "When main thread can lock the mutex, `processed` will already be true". The worker thread may not even have started yet, or if it has it may not have seen that `ready` is set.

Comment: The answer to your question is stated in the answer to that question.

Comment: I see it now. I am just learning c++ concurrency and thought that 'cv.notify_one();' from main causes that 'worker_thread' immediately locks the mutex. So it could happen that main locks and releases it for the second time, and 'worker_thread' locks it just after that?

Comment: Yes. Things can (and do) happen in an unexpected order. Locks and condition variables make it possible to reason about behaviour even when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Line `cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});` does the following if `ready` is `false`:

1. Unlocks the mutex `lk`
2. Blocks the thread waiting for notification
3. When notification arrives, unblocks the thread and locks the mutex `lk`

So the main thread does not block on `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);` as the mutex is unlocked by worker thread.

Comment: My question refers to the lock in main.

Comment: When the main thread tries to lock, the worker thread is blocked on cv.wait and the mutex is unlocked